# Swift: getting AppDelegate instance as a class func results in Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I want to get my AppDelegate reference from a `class func` in my `AppDelegate`. Why is this throwing a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`?

```
class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

I have also tried to move this to another utility class and as a regular `func`, but getting the same crash.

Is there a way I can access the `AppDelegate` as a `class func` instead of having to write

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

in every class?

Comment: class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
} is working. Can you tell how you are declaring this function?

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case xcode crashes so I never get the chance to debug it. Maybe one must simply create a class just for this, and then let all other classes inherit it. That would be a little less work, but still annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Declare class function to get appDelegate in AppDelegate class as

```
class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

To access and use appDelegate in other class, call

```
    let delegate = AppDelegate.getDelegate()

    delegate.printHello()
```

Comment: This is exactly how I am doing it, but I am getting the crash exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class as shown below[in a new class file or in existing class file outside the previous class. *No need to put it inside `AppDelete.swift` file*]

```
class Delegate
{
   static var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

and you can use it as `Delegate.appDelegate` in any class.